# Monodevelop and Gtk Treeview

Tags: c#, mono, treeview, monodevelop, gtk#

I'm creating a system using monodevelop. I need to implement the Gtk TreeView to display the data. I already followed the instructions [here](http://www.mono-project.com/GtkSharp_TreeView_Tutorial) but still, it does not work.

My problem is I'm generating my treeview on the class. Here is my code:

On MainWindow.cs

```
protected void OnShowCustomerTab (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    customer.treeViewTable(customerTreeView);
}
```

On my class

```
public void treeViewTable(Gtk.TreeView tree)
    {
        tree = new Gtk.TreeView();
        tree.Hide();

        // generate tree column
        Gtk.TreeViewColumn lineNoColumn = new Gtk.TreeViewColumn();
        Gtk.CellRendererText lineNoCell = new Gtk.CellRendererText();
        lineNoColumn.Title = "#";
        lineNoColumn.PackStart(lineNoCell, true);
        lineNoColumn.AddAttribute(lineNoCell, "text", 0);

        Gtk.TreeViewColumn customerCodeColumn = new Gtk.TreeViewColumn();
        Gtk.CellRendererText customerCodeCell = new Gtk.CellRendererText();
        customerCodeColumn.Title = "Customer Code";
        customerCodeColumn.PackStart(customerCodeCell, true);
        customerCodeColumn.AddAttribute(customerCodeCell, "text", 1);

        // append the column and data on the tree table
        tree.AppendColumn(lineNoColumn);
        tree.AppendColumn(customerCodeColumn);

        tree.Show();
    }
```

Is there a problem in my code? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I solved it. It just needs to set the treeview model, even if it has no record, to display the columns.

Comment: You can use the "answer my own question" option in order to leave it here for documentation purposes.

Comment: Perhaps you could update your answer with a working solution

Answer (score 0):

Here you are creating your own treeview manually, but you could also use the designer, and then make sure to name your treeview. Here is an example - put this after build() in MainWindow :

```
    // Create a column for the name
    Gtk.TreeViewColumn nameColumn = new Gtk.TreeViewColumn ();
    nameColumn.Title = "Name";

    // Create a column for the song title
    Gtk.TreeViewColumn sColumn = new Gtk.TreeViewColumn ();
    sColumn.Title = "Song Title";

    // Add the columns to the TreeView
    this.<NameOfYourNodeView>.NodeSelection.NodeView.AppendColumn(nameColumn);
    this.<NameOfYourNodeView>.NodeSelection.NodeView.AppendColumn(sColumn);

    // Create a model that will hold two strings -  Name and Song Title
    Gtk.ListStore mListStore = new Gtk.ListStore (typeof (string), typeof (string));

    // Assign the model to the TreeView
    this.<NameOfYourNodeView>.NodeSelection.NodeView.Model = mListStore;

    // Add some data to the store
    mListStore.AppendValues ("Garbage", "Dog New Tricks");

    // Create the text cell that will display the artist name
    Gtk.CellRendererText NameCell = new Gtk.CellRendererText ();

    // Add the cell to the column
    nameColumn.PackStart (NameCell, true);

    // Do the same for the song title column
    Gtk.CellRendererText sTitleCell = new Gtk.CellRendererText ();
    sColumn.PackStart (sTitleCell, true);

    // Tell the Cell Renderers which items in the model to display
    nameColumn.AddAttribute (NameCell, "text", 0);
    sColumn.AddAttribute (sTitleCell, "text", 1);
```

> result (inside your treeview):

```
Name     Song Title
Garbage  Dog New Tricks
```